# *|UNSUB|* does not get parsed in mandrill template

Tags: mandrill, mailmerge, unsubscribe

I am using `*|UNSUB|*` merge tag in the mandrill template, which I expect to automatically parse it when the mail is sent using this template (without doing anything in the code). My template code is,

`<a href = "*|UNSUB: https://mywebsite.com/unsub|*">Unsubscribe from this list.</a>;`

Question 1:
It does not get parsed and ignores the anchor tag all together and displays "Unsubscribe from this list" text as a simple text, not hyperlink. I have tried setting the merge option in sending default settings to handlebars and mailchimp, but no luck.

Question 2:
The default option to add the unsubscribe link by checking the "add unsubscribe footer" in the settings is working fine. However, I would like to add a custom message like

You are getting this message since you are registered with us, if you do not want to get any mails from us, please 'unsubscribe'.

I want the 'unsubscribe' in the above sentence as a link which points to the link given by mandrill by default. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance,
Kari...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably a moot point by now but changing the text works now for unsubscribe links in Mandrill.

This is working sample code from one of our templates:

```
<tr>
     <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 0px 18px 9px; text-align: center;">
        <a href="*|UNSUB:https://www.example.com/unsubscribe-successful/|*">
            Whatever you want to say about unsubscribing.
        </a> | 
        <a href="https://www.example.com/privacy/">Privacy Policy</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I've tested this in one of our templates and it works:

```
<p>You are getting this message since you are 
   registered with us, if you do not want to 
   get any mails from us, please
   <a href="*|UNSUB:https://example.com/unsubscribe/|*">
   'unsubscribe'</a>.
</p>
```

Just a couple of doh! caveats that might save someone a few minutes:

1. If you send yourself a test of the template and click the unsubscribe link, Mandrill will throw a delivery error if you try to resend that template to the same email address again - you've really unsubscribed.
2. Clicking the unsubscribe when previewing the template in Mandrill throws an error that can be ignored. You will need to send a test email to test that link. Keep in mind point 1.

Answer (score -1):

Mandrill's UNSUB merge tag requires some additional parameters that you can read about here: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205583017-Can-I-add-an-automatic-unsubscribe-link-to-Mandrill-emails-

So you'll need to use this format instead:

```
<a href="*|UNSUB:http://mywebsite.com/unsub|*">Unsubscribe from this list.</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, As explained I am using the exact format as you have mentioned, but it does not get parsed.

Note: The * is being stripped from the text in my description, but I am using the same format as you have used. Also, did you look into my 2nd question?

Comment: Hi can anyone please help me in this, as I am still facing the same issue of UNSUB not being parsed to a right url, even after following the right syntax.